# Scalar or array function

Tags: arrays, perl, function, scalar

I have to do function which will work as scalar and as array. For example:

```
@t = testfunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
$x = testfunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Anbody have idea how I can do it?
It have to print "scalar" if it's $x and print "array" if @t. I tried to do something like this:

```
sub testfunc()
{
   print "test";
}
```

But even this doesn't work :/

Comment: As others have noted, you would use `wantarray`for this. See `perldoc -f wantarray` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html

Comment: Don't use prototypes (the empty parentheses after sub name). Their usage is *only* to override the normal subroutine functionality, to create obscure things that mimic the behaviour of some built-ins.

Comment: @TLP: unless you have 5.20+ and have enabled the experimental signatures (but even there, `()` is inappropriate in this case)

Comment: Welcome to SO you are off to a fair start.  This is still a relevant question (though perhaps a FAQ) and pretty well asked here. Since it doesn't effect the substance of the responses I think you should correct `sub testfunc() { ... } ` to `sub testfunc {... }` in your question since they shouldn't be used to define the subroutine unless you need prototypes / signatures as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

This feature is named "call context". Use the [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) keyword.

```
@t = testfunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
$x = testfunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
sub testfunc {
    if ( wantarray ) {
        print "List context\n";
    }
    # False, but defined
    elsif ( defined wantarray ) {
        print "Scalar context\n";
    }
    # False and undefined
    else {
        print "Void context\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a function in perl  called [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) which returns:

- `true` if the sub is called in a list context
- `false` if scalar
- `undef` if neither.

As an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub wantarray_test {

    if ( not defined wantarray() ) {
        print "Called in void context by ", caller(), "\n";
    }
    else {
        if ( wantarray() ) {
            print "Called in list context by ", caller(), "\n";
            return ( "A", "list", "of", "results" );
        }
        else {
            print "called in a scalar context by ", caller(), "\n";
            return "scalar result";
        }
    }

}

my @result = wantarray_test();
print "@result\n";

my $result = wantarray_test();
print $result, "\n";

wantarray_test();
```

Bonus question:

What do you think you'll get if you:

```
print wantarray_test();
```

You can do even more than this if you're so inclined with [`Contextual::Return`](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Contextual-Return-0.004007/lib/Contextual/Return.pm) - this will allow you to test for more detailed contexts, such as the difference between `scalar` and `boolean`. (This is useful for example, if you'd want to test a percentage - you may not want to treat '0' as 'false').

But be careful with context sensitive functions. It's quite easy to build in some unexpected behaviour, which is something that can bite you badly down the line.

As a related note - you should not declare your sub the way you have. There's a mechanism in perl called prototypes that define what sort of arguments your subroutine is expecting. See: [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). You should not define your sub as:

```
sub testfunc() 
{   
     # some stuff
}
```

This specifies a prototype, and should be avoided unless you're sure that's what you want.

Comment: add something about the OP's bad prototype

Comment: Wow .. this is really really good. Thanks!  Adding a reference to this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) function

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say my $x = testfunc(1,2,3,4);
say my @x = testfunc(1,2,3,4);

sub testfunc {
    return wantarray ? @_ : "@_";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The strangely named [`wantarray`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#wantarray) is the standard approach - it lets you distinguish between list and scalar contexts. You can also use [`Want`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Want) from CPAN which goes a bit further than the standard `wantarray` builtin function (see the [`Want` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Want)).

The following should return the same results as the `wantarray` solutions:

```
use Want;
sub testfuncadelic {
  if (want('LIST')) { 
    rreturn @_; }  
  elsif (want('SCALAR')) { 
    rreturn "@_" ; } 
  return 
}
```

The following should cut and paste into a shell as a pseudo-"oneliner" (Unix syntax) to demonstrate:

```
% cpanm Want
% perl -MWant -E '
sub testfunc { 
if (want("LIST")) { 
   rreturn "array in list context ", @_;}
elsif (want("SCALAR")) { 
   rreturn "string in scalar context @_"; } 
return }
$result =  testfunc(qw/1 2 3 4/ ); say $result; 
@results = testfunc(qw/1 2 3 4/ ); say @results;'
```

**Output**

```
string in scalar context 1 2 3 4
array in list context 1234
```

**Edit**

@Sobrique has the most thorough treatment of the standard approach here - he/she would get my acceptance if I had asked the question.  One thing I neglected above is that (obviously, 'doh!) if `wantarray` is `undef` then you have void context! Perhaps I assumed this and didn't realize it could be used explicitly to detect void contxt. So `wantarray` can give you all three of the standard calling contexts. `Wanted` on the other hand is about tricky fun stuff and I did not mean to imply it should be used *instead* of `wantarray`. I still think `wantarray` should have a better name :-)